# onClick event not getting called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing my first code in JavaScript.

I want to do this :-

- Load an image
- Ask for user name
- after writing the name change the image
- and show user's name in alert

My code goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iRock - First Project</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function touchRock(){

    var userName = prompt ("what is your name?","Enter your name here.");

    if(userName){
        alert("It is good to meet you, " "+userName+ " ".");
        document.getElementById("firstImg").src="1.jpg";
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload = "alert('hello, I am your pet.');">
        <div style = "margin-top:100px; text-align:centre">
                 <img id="firstImg" src="http://www.smiley-faces.org/wallpaper/smiley-face-wallpaper-widescreen-001.jpg" alt="iRock" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="touchRock()" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in this? The event is not getting called after touching the image.

Comment: First thing you should do is learn to use the Javascript console in your browser. It will point out when you have syntax errors in your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DfSHS/ -- error in your alert statement, fiddle is the fix.

Comment: @user814628 If you're going to answer the question, post it in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Head first Javascript? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string concatination is wrong  inside the function

`alert("It is good to meet you, " "+userName+ " ".");` you must be getting error in the console.

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/98scQ/)

```
function touchRock(){

    var userName = prompt ("what is your name?","Enter your name here.");

    if(userName){
        alert("It is good to meet you, " + userName +  ".");
        document.getElementById("firstImg").src="1.jpg";
    }
}
```

if you are using Chrome. press F12 --> you will get developer tool bar enabled, in that there will be console where you can see any errors, debug javascript inspect elements etc.. SImilarly you have Firebug for FireFox and DevToolbar for Int Explorer.

[Script Debugger in Chrome - Ref](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts)

Comment: Thanks man , So fast , It worked like a charm . BTW , I can only accept answer after 11 Mins :(

Comment: For Chrome/mac SHortcut keys check this--> https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

You are not preforming string concatenation correctly in your alert.

Change this:

```
alert("It is good to meet you, " "+userName+ " ".");
```

To this:

```
alert("It is good to meet you, " + userName + ".");
```

To concatenate two strings together the + operator must sit outside of the strings.

```
var newString = "I am " + "a concatenated string";
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u can use 
alert( "It is good to meet you, "+ userName + "." ) ;

instead of 
alert("It is good to meet you, " "+userName+ " ".");

As per my knowledge, in javascript we usually use  "+" symbol for concatenation .